# How to capture the entire program pipe output upon the source program termination?

Tags: node.js

I have two programs:

1. Prints long output and crashes straight after producing the output.
2. Simply performs `process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);`

I pipe the program #1 output to program #2.

What happens is that if program #1 produces long output and terminates, **the program #2 terminates before finishing to print the output**.

`a.js`:

```
let index = 0;
let output = '';

while (index < 1000000) {
  output += ' ' + (index++);
}

console.log(output);

throw new Error('test');
```

`b.js`:

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

test:

```
node a.js | b.js
```

**`b.js` program produces only partial output of the `a.js` input.**

You can test it using the above code fragments. Seems to be consistent behaviour across the latest [node](/questions/tagged/node) versions.

How to capture the entire program pipe output upon the source program termination?

To replicate in the CLI:

```
node --eval "let index = 0; let output = ''; while (index < 1000000) { output += ' ' + (index++); } console.log(output); throw new Error('test');" | node --eval 'process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);'
```

Notice that the last number is not 999999 (on my system it is always 12773), but rather some number in the middle of the sequence.

Using `process.stdout.write` instead of `console.log` does not change the behaviour.

After further inspection, it appears that the same can be replicated using `cat`.

```
node --eval "let index = 0; let output = ''; while (index < 1000000) { output += ' ' + (index++); } console.log(output); throw new Error('test');" | cat
```

Is it even possible to solve the issue from the perspective of the program that accepts the input?

Comment: You mean `process.stderr.pipe(process.stdout)` ? or log to other file via shell `node a.js 2> error_log | node b.js`

Comment: Whether `stderr` is included or is irrelevant. I want to capture all the output that `a.js` program produced before quitting.

Comment: eh, `node a.js 2>&1 | node b.js`

Comment: @PPang Please read the question again – I have highlighted the problem.

Comment: The only thing which is missing from `b.js`'s output is `a.js`'s stderr. And redirecting `a.js`'s stderr to stdout worked for me.

Comment: @PPang Run `node --eval "let index = 0; let output = ''; while (index < 1000000) { output += ' ' + (index++); } console.log(output); throw new Error('test');" | node --eval 'process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);'` in the CLI and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Temp solution, log to a file : `node a.js > a.txt ; node b.js < a.txt`

Comment: @puritys That is going to suffer from the same behaviour.

Comment: Ended up raising an issue with Node https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20687.

Comment: @Gajus I think the root cause is the process of transferring data to linux pipe not nodejs. My solution is using  semicolon ";" to replace pipe "|". It works for me.